# Hesitant to inform my suspected tuberculosis to my employer

Tags: professionalism, india, health

I was recently diagnosed with health issue with diagnosis results saying 'Strong Suspect" for tuberculosis. Although my diagnosis doesn't say that I am positive for tuberculosis, the physician has started my treatment with anti tuberculosis treatment.

This is an extrapulmonary tuberculosis, means it is not contagious and there is no harm to people around me. Also this was early stage detection hence I haven't even developed any symptoms. Most likely I will be recovered in 3 to 4 months.

This doesn't affect my work abilities at present and due to work from home I am anyway not in physical contact with my work colleagues. However, most of the Indians have seen bad phases of tuberculosis and there is social stigma attached with this illness.

People still think that tuberculosis automatically relates to death and they keep their distance from infected people. Keeping all the things in mind, I am little hesitant to inform this condition to my employer. Requesing the peers on this platform to guide me dealing with it professionally.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: @Tymoteusz Paul I am in India

Comment: Do you need to take time off because of this? Why do you feel a need to tell them?

Comment: @AsheraH I don't need to take any time off par present but I can't tell what situation may arrive in future. The employer might get to know about this condition due to the health insurance provided by the employer. In case offices opens in next few months then it would be risky for me to go to office with pandemic around since my immune response is already affected.

Comment: Not sure how it goes in India, but in most places paying for your health insurance doesn't give any access to your medical file to your employer...

Comment: One of the reasons to hesitate is that many people think a health failure is somehow embarrassing.  If this is part of the reason, please reconsider.  It is far more embarrassing to be the cause of other people's health problems, and it is noble to take action to keep your coworkers healthy.  If your company is offered the chance to see this scenario in that light, and they really can accommodate you working from home, then it will be fine.  If your company doesn't see it that way, or they can't handle you working from home, it gets complicated.  Ask a local lawyer.

Comment: @EdwinBuck still, it's not necessary to disclose the specific condition. All the employer has to know is that you're sick and possibly contagious, so it's better if you stay home for a while.

Answer (score 12):

Unless you have a formal obligation, under your contract or local labour laws, there's no need for you to disclose the specific condition to your employer. Doesn't matter if they somehow find out - through insurance or otherwise - again, you're not obligated to inform them.

As you mentioned you're currently working remotely and don't need to be taking any sick time off, so just continue with your job as usual. If you end up being called back to the office and you're worried this might damage your health or endanger your coworkers you might ask your doctor for a medical note recommending work from home, without disclosing your condition.

Comment: In some countries this is a very dangerous approach.  If you hit somebody's car, you are liable for the damages.  If you give your office TB (unlikely, but possible) you could be liable for damages too.  And, in most places, a fully office of TB cases will trigger a health worker to figure out and contain the spread (meaning you will get caught).

Comment: There would perhaps be protocols for such situations, in which case yes, the condition has to be reported. Without any protocols, there's no obligation to report it. The OP should definitely ensure they're not breaking any laws and consult with their medical care specialist.

Comment: Generally, most legal systems see a basic level of restoring people back to (as close as possible) what they were before, by moving money (the only easily transferable item).  It isn't based on "if there is protocol"  Also, culturally, few people sue on disease; however, there are cases where disease carriers who knowingly infected others, even while performing their work duties to make a living, have been convicted and imprisoned for (in the case I'm thinking of) repeated violations.  Also, do you think your office will welcome you after you make them all sick? You might need a new job anyway

Comment: I can understand the hesitation.  And my comments applly more to the USA than India, and even in the USA, people are not likely to raise such a lawsuit.  If you are truly non-transmissible, then I can understand being quiet about the matter too.  But, if you are worried that you _should_ be non-transmissable (with a slight chance of transmission), and you have a good employer, maybe they can permit you to work from home for a few months.  It all depends on details.

Comment: @EdwinBuck it should still be possible (I hope) for the OP to communicate with their employer through a doctor's note, without disclosing the condition but notifying them that the best course of action is for them to work from home. Unless there are any local laws that the OP should abide by and that state differently.

Comment: @EdwinBuck, In which case, he should ask his doctor for his advice. But since the doctor said that it isn't contagious, then I doubt very much that the doctor would suggest disclosing such a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I need to disclose the health condition formally now. The organization needs to me to perform site supervision for a period of 4 to 5days, for an outstation project location. As per my experience, the physical exertion develops fever on the same day. Hence, I will not be able to perform this particular task. I have already informed this to my supervisor verbally but I will be submitting a formal note from my physician.